# Как передать бинарный файл Java Servlet -> html (js)

Tags: javascript, java, servlet, клиент-сервер

С сервлета на клиент необходимо отправить торрент-файл. В JS не силён. По примерам в интернете скопипастил такой код.

```
            function downloadFile() {  
                var data;
                var xmlHttp = getXHR();
                var date = new Date();
                date = Date.parse(date);

                xmlHttp.open("GET", "/index?request=dld&sessid=" + date, false);
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
                        if(xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                            data = this.response;

                            saveData(data, fileName); //код получения fileName опускаю

                        }
                    }
                };

                xmlHttp.send(null);

            }

            function getXHR() {
                var xmlHttp;
                try {
                    xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    try {
                        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
                    } catch (E) {
                        xmlHttp = false;
                    }
                }

                if (!xmlHttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
                    xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }

                return xmlHttp;
            }

            var saveData = (function () {
                debugger;
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.style = "display: none";
                return function (data, fileName) {

                    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "octet/stream"}),
                    url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = fileName;
                    a.click();
                    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                };
            }());
```

код сервлета:

```
            String path = "--any path--";
            OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(path);
            while(inputStream.available() > 0){
                outputStream.write(inputStream.read());
            }

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
```

Файл сохраняется ломаный. Если просто открыть в текстовом или hex редакторе, то начало файла, где перечисляются трекеры, сходится с исходным, а дальше, где бинарная информация, идет явное отличие.

Comment: Каким образом файл поступает на сервлет?

Comment: new FileInputStream(path); вот поток чтения

Answer (score 1):

**Решено**

Несмотря на то, что минусуют, я всё же отвечу. Вдруг, кому поможет. 
Для объекта XMLHttpRequest необходимо указать тип принимаемых данных. 
В моём случае

```
xmlHttp.responseType = "arraybuffer";
```

Данная настройка работает только с асинхронным запросом.
По умолчанию xmlHttp.responseType = "" (DOMString), что и приводит к изменению данных.